# Set non-active class with uri-segment CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, uri, helper

i'm trying to use uri segment to add class active and non-active for my navigation menu. this is my code.

```
<li <?php echo $uri1 == "admin" ? "class='active'" : "class=''"; ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
</li>

<li <?php echo $uri1 == "admin" || $uri2 == "admin/categories" ? "class='active'" : "class=''"; ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin/categories"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cubes"></i> Categories</a>
</li>
```

but when i tried this one, they both got active class on their list even it's not their current page. And the case is: how to set one non-active class if it's not their current page. Will appreciate any help, thanks before!

Comment: what value you getting for `$uri1` and `$uri2`

Comment: @Bankzilla true || true should get class='' not active

Comment: @ShaifulIslam yeah i realised after writing that the  class output has been switched around. Surprised that the second one is returning false considering it's returning true in the first case.

Comment: hey guys, sorry for pasted the wrong code. i've edited the code now.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you used the `||` insted of `&&`. Try this:

```
 <li <?php echo $uri1 == "admin" ? "class='active'" : "class=''"; ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
    </li>

    <li <?php echo $uri1 == "admin" && $uri2 == "admin/categories" ? "class='active'" : "class=''"; ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin/categories"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cubes"></i> Categories</a>
    </li>
```